# Scrapy Parse function not yielding output

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm having a heck of a time with this script. I can't seem to get the parse function to yield the output I need to print the variables.  Is there something I'm just missing?

```
Import requests_html
import scrapy
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

class BillingsorgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "billingsorg"
    allowed_domains = ["billings.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.billings.org/agents/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
        'name': response.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/div/section/div/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/h3/text()').get().strip(),
        'phone': response.xpath('//div[@class="staff-phone"]/i/following-sibling::text()').get().strip(),
        'email': response.css('a[href^="mailto"]::attr(href)').get(),
        'company': response.xpath('//div[@class="staff-company"]/i/following-sibling::text()').get().strip()
        }
  
print(name, phone, email, company)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues,

1. Your first import statement will cause a syntax error because of the `I`
2. requests_html lib is not being used and unnecessary
3. your print statement is outside of the scope of your parse function, so all the variables your are trying to print do not exist.
4. You are only yielding a single item when I assume you want to get the information for all of the listed realtors
5. you are using absolute xpaths which are very error prone.

Here is an example that avoids all those issues.

```
import scrapy
# No unneeded imports

class BillingsorgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "billingsorg"
    allowed_domains = ["billings.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.billings.org/agents/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # iterate through each of the realtors
        for staff in response.css('div.staff-capsule'):
            # gather contact information for each realtor
            item = {
                'name': staff.xpath('.//h3//text()').get().strip(),
                'phone': ''.join(staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-phone"]//text()').getall()).strip(),
                'email': staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-email"]//a/@href').get(),
                'company': ''.join(staff.xpath('.//div[@class="staff-company"]//text()').getall()).strip()
            }
            print(item)  # print the item here in the scope of the method
            yield item   # yield to output processor
```

then run `scrapy crawl billingsorg`

and you should see something like this:

```
{'name': 'Real Estate By Hamwey', 'phone': '406-698-2020', 'email': 'mailto:hamwey@hamwey.com', 'company': 'Real Estate By Hamwey'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Real Estate By Hamwey', 'phone': '406-698-2020', 'email': 'mailto:hamwey@hamwey.com', 'company': 'Real Estate By Hamwey'}
{'name': 'Kristy Aasheim', 'phone': '406-480-9383', 'email': 'mailto:montanadakotaagent@gmail.com', 'company': 'RE/MAX of Billings'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Kristy Aasheim', 'phone': '406-480-9383', 'email': 'mailto:montanadakotaagent@gmail.com', 'company': 'RE/MAX of Billings'}
{'name': 'J.D. Adams', 'phone': '406-633-3288', 'email': 'mailto:jadamsrealtor17@gmail.com', 'company': 'Red Truck Real Estate'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'J.D. Adams', 'phone': '406-633-3288', 'email': 'mailto:jadamsrealtor17@gmail.com', 'company': 'Red Truck Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Randall Adams', 'phone': '406-390-4040', 'email': 'mailto:ACR_Adams@msn.com', 'company': 'Rankin Realty'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Randall Adams', 'phone': '406-390-4040', 'email': 'mailto:ACR_Adams@msn.com', 'company': 'Rankin Realty'}
{'name': 'Monna Rae Adickes', 'phone': '406-860-4284', 'email': 'mailto:monnarae@cbthebrokers.com', 'company': 'Coldwell Banker The Brokers'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Monna Rae Adickes', 'phone': '406-860-4284', 'email': 'mailto:monnarae@cbthebrokers.com', 'company': 'Coldwell Banker The Brokers'}
{'name': 'Tambra Akins', 'phone': '406-672-2318', 'email': 'mailto:tammy.akins@ymail.com', 'company': 'Western Skies Real Estate'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Tambra Akins', 'phone': '406-672-2318', 'email': 'mailto:tammy.akins@ymail.com', 'company': 'Western Skies Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Asia Alder', 'phone': '406-855-2742', 'email': 'mailto:asia@asiaalder.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Asia Alder', 'phone': '406-855-2742', 'email': 'mailto:asia@asiaalder.com', 'company': 'Real Estate Hub LLLP'}
{'name': 'Roger Aldinger', 'phone': '406-671-1440', 'email': 'mailto:roger@mcn.net', 'company': 'Aldinger Real Estate'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Roger Aldinger', 'phone': '406-671-1440', 'email': 'mailto:roger@mcn.net', 'company': 'Aldinger Real Estate'}
{'name': 'Ginny Alegria', 'phone': '406-861-4512', 'email': 'mailto:ginny@livingwatersrealtymontana.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
2023-02-27 13:57:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.billings.org/agents/>
{'name': 'Ginny Alegria', 'phone': '406-861-4512', 'email': 'mailto:ginny@livingwatersrealtymontana.com', 'company': 'eXp Realty, LLC'}
```

Comment: Now that I have the basic scraper working, I can't figure out how to make it go to the next page and scrape that information, then the next page, etc. until all the pages are scraped and put into a .csv file.  I'm really new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @LarryHines  Open a new question with your current code and detailed description of the current issues you are facing.